# python json binding: why write code like this?

Tags: python, twitter

I am using some open SNS webiste's API, the python version is a binding to its JSON version, but I really can't understand below, why do things like this?

```
def mentions(self):
    comments = self.api.mentions()
    for comment in comments:
        self.obj = comment
        mid = self.getAtt("id")
        text = self.getAtt("text")
        print "mentions---"+ str(mid) +":"+ text
```

Why not access comment's own attribute but assign to self.obj?

Comment: Do you have access to the implementation of `getAtt` of the parent class?

Comment: [check this one](http://ideone.com/OfIft) to see what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `comment` isn't amenable to direct attribute access. If so...

It looks like the API was designed by a Java programmer. A more Pythonic solution — assuming you can't access the attributes of `comment` directly — would be to rename the `getAtt` method to `__getattr__` and write, e.g., `mid = self.id`.

But even then the idea of assigning each `comment` to `self.obj` in turn seems perverse. Some wrapper around `comment` would probably be better:

```
c = attrgetter(comment)
mid = c.id
⋮
```

In fact, this would be sufficiently concise that you would even bother with local variables:

```
c = attrgetter(comment)
print "mentions---"+ str(c.mid) +":"+ c.text
```